# How to remove outer white space around an image in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, image, border, crop

I am new to c# and wanted to develop an app which can remove outer white space of image, image is surrounded with black border so it can easily be cropped and removed outer white space.

I am attaching to two image before and after cropping, as you can see Image 2 is cropped and outer  white space is removed, furthermore, its rotation is also adjusted to make image proper in rectangle format. Finally, the size of image is 800x1200 pixels from 1946x2817

Image before cropping [1946x2817] with outer space and border [image]
Image after cropped [800x1200] without outer space and border [image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please share the code you developed?

Comment: It is already cropped so it seems you have been successful. If you have done it with another tool you might want to think about automating that tool with something like c#. Coding this from zero isn't a problem you should approach when you are new to programming.

Comment: This is way too broad for a question here. You would need to find the position and angle of the border by scanning the pixels from all sides for it and then rotate using graphics.RotateTransform and finally crop by using DrawImage with two rectangles as params. Good luck!

Comment: We have an application using it for the above purpose but do not have code to modify the algorithm as our requirements are changed and sometimes that application fails to crop some images.

We do not have any source code of that application and I tried some of techniques to recover the code/decompile but could not get success. 

Now, the issue is that some of images are blur and our application does not works on blured image and we want to change some threshold of croping the images.

I can share the application if anyone need.

Comment: @TaW I can understand the algorithm but I thought there might be any tools used for this purpose in .Net or might be any application already developed [with source code available in github].

Comment: Well I'm sure are but you will need to search for them on your own, as asking for toll libs etc makes the question off topic as well..